# angularjs assign scope function to scope variable says function is not a function

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-scope

at application load on first time I want to calculate a value and assign it to `$scope.about`

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location,$route) {
    $scope.var1 = 'some value'; /*this works*/

    $scope.about = $scope.getAbout(); //ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
    /*above line throws error saying $scope.getAbout is not a function*/   
    $scope.getAbout = function(){
        var a = /* get it from webservice via $http */
        a = process a;
        return a;
    }

    $scope.otherFunction = function(){
        //if I call $scope.getAbout here from inside another function it works fine.
        $scope.about = $scope.getAbout(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: $scope.about = $scope.getAbout();  this will not work before getAbout is defined. try to call after function is defined

Answer (score 0):

You use `$scope.getAbout` before you defined it. First define the function, then use it.

```
$scope.about = $scope.getAbout(); // This WILL throw an error

// Define the function
$scope.getAbout = function(){
    var a = /* get it from webservice via $http */
    a = process a;
    return a;
}

$scope.about = $scope.getAbout(); // This WON'T throw an error
```

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work in [this pen](https://codepen.io/yadejo/pen/rzLxEG).

Comment: yes i saw at above pen, but not working the same with me, I am using AngularJS v1.6.5

Comment: Based on the code example you gave in the original question, I'm afraid I won't be able to help any further than this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return a from function $scope.getAbout just use this. hope it will work.

```
 $scope.getAbout = function(){
         var a = /* get it from webservice via $http */
         a = process a;
        $scope.about  = a;
         return false; 
   }
```

**no need to use $scope.about = $scope.getAbout();**